# How to define a web component well formatted custom event?

Tags: dom, web-component, stenciljs, custom-events

I'm trying to define a coding standard for my company's design system's web components but I'm not sure what would be the best choice.

There are people which is [strongly against the use of uppercase](https://gomakethings.com/custom-event-naming-conventions/) in event names, due to the fact that would not be compatible with DOM Level 2, but the [DOM Level 3 is defined by almost 20 years](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/), so I don't understand the problem.

This would be my choice but I'm not sure if DOM Level 2 is so important:

| Event name | Compatibility | Readability | Code handling | Best candidate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `accordiontimermouseenteractive` | DOM Level 2 | *Worse* | **Best** |  |
| `accordiontimer:mouseenteractive` | DOM Level 2 | *Bad* | *Bad* |  |
| `accordionTimerMouseEnterActive` | DOM Level 3 | Good | **Best** | ✅ |
| `accordionTimer:MouseEnter:Active` | DOM Level 3 | **Best** | *Worse* |  |

For *code handling* I just mean how the event is easy to be copied and pasted with the clipboard.

I'm using StenciJS to create the suite, so this would be my TypeScript scenary:

```js
@Event({ eventName: 'accordionTimerMouseEnterActive' }) mouseEnterActiveEvent: EventEmitter
```

On **DOM Level 2/3** [I didn't found any compatibility informations](https://caniuse.com/?search=DOM%20Level%203), so what would be the better choice, is **DOM Level 2** so important in 2023?

Comment: You have been on SO long enough to know they will flag this question as Opinion based.. for what its worth; I would do ``accordion_timer_mouseenter_active`` No colons so save to use in HTML and easy to split on _ to extract info

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i’ll add your proposal to the private issue.